# No specs found while executing jasmine test via bazel

Tags: typescript, bazel, jasmine-node

I'm tring to run jasmine test using bazel on my current directory, but it is complaining about no specs found.

I think it has something to do with the "srcs" variable that I am providing.
I tried `[":spec/test.spec.ts"]` and `[":spec"]` but none is working.

Command that I use: bazel run //packages/core:unit_test

File directory:

root

-packages

--core

---spec

----test.spec.ts

```
jasmine_node_test(
    name = "unit_test",
    srcs = [":spec/test.spec.ts"],
    deps = [
        "@npm//jasmine"
    ],
)
```

test.spec.ts

```
describe("A suite is just a function", function() {
  var a;

  it("and so is a spec", function() {
    a = true;

    expect(a).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bazel/bazel": "^0.24.1",
    "@bazel/buildifier": "^0.22.0",
    "@bazel/ibazel": "^0.10.2",
    "@bazel/typescript": "^0.28.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bazel/jasmine": "^0.32.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.13",
    "jasmine": "^3.4.0"
  }
```

I expect the test to run successfully.

Comment: What npm packages exactly are you using? Can you for instance list the dependencies in your package.json file. That would help reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in a sample application using Bazel and it seems like you need to transpile your code to JS **because you are trying to run a .ts file in a JS test runner**.

Note: In your case a simple rename to `*.js` will suffice (I checked).

---

### Sample code to achieve what you want

**BUILD.bazel**

```
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")
load("@npm_bazel_jasmine//:index.bzl", "jasmine_node_test")

ts_library(
    name = "files_to_compile",
    srcs = ["test.spec.ts"]
)

jasmine_node_test(
    name = "sampletest",
    srcs = [":files_to_compile"]
)
```

OR

```
load("@npm_bazel_jasmine//:index.bzl", "jasmine_node_test")

jasmine_node_test(
    name = "sampletest",
    srcs = ["test.spec.js"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `glob`, which is inspired by rules from [bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/examples](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/blob/master/examples/bazel_managed_deps/BUILD.bazel).

```
srcs = glob(["*.spec.ts"]),
```

Comment: Tried that... Still the same error. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with jasmine.json. If I run my test through jasmine instead of bazel, it works.

Comment: Have you tried any of the examples in the repo that I linked in my answer? Some of them run Jasmine. I'd be interested to know whether they work for you.